# How to use plop with ngxs

Tags: ngxs, plop

In ngxs [cli](https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/cli) documentation there is an option to use plopfile. I played with it for a while but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Does anybody know how to use `plop` with `ngxs` ?

Answer (score 0):

NGXS has it's own `plopfile` it uses for the CLI commands it offers. They have allowed developers to use their own `plopfile` to extend these templates.

Using the basic example as per the [plopjs website](https://plopjs.com/documentation/), create a `plopfile` in your root, and call it whatever: `custom-plopfile.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (plop) {
    // controller generator
    plop.setGenerator('controller', {
        description: 'application controller logic',
        prompts: [{
            type: 'input',
            name: 'name',
            message: 'controller name please'
        }],
        actions: [{
            type: 'add',
            path: 'src/{{name}}.js',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/controller.hbs'
        }]
    });
};
```

To execute this, you could run: `ngxs --plopfile ./custom-plopfile.js GreetingController` and it will use the custom plopfile and template, to generate a new controller for you as `src/GreetingController.js`.